# NBitcoin Transaction sign(secret, bool) is giving error. Instead of bool it says to pass Coin

Tags: c#, blockchain, bitcoin, nbitcoin

I am using NBitcoin to sign a transaction. Here Transaction sign(secret, bool) method is giving error.
(I've search the Internet, but no help.) Instead of bool it says to pass Coin object, how should I do this?
Here's my code:

```
var fee = Money.Coins(0.0001m);

        Transaction payment=Transaction.Create(bitcoinNetwork);
        payment.Inputs.Add(new TxIn()
        {
            PrevOut = new OutPoint(fundingTransaction.GetHash(), 1)
        });

        payment.Outputs.Add(new TxOut()
        {
            Value = amount-fee,
            ScriptPubKey = toAddress.ScriptPubKey
        });

        var output = fundingTransaction.Outputs[0];
       

        payment.Outputs.Add(new TxOut()
        {
            Value = output.Value - amount - fee,
            ScriptPubKey = output.ScriptPubKey
        });

        var message = "Thanks :)";
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        payment.Outputs.Add(new TxOut()
        {
            Value = Money.Zero,
            ScriptPubKey = TxNullDataTemplate.Instance.GenerateScriptPubKey(bytes)
        });

        Console.WriteLine(payment);

        payment.Inputs[0].ScriptSig = fundingTransaction.Outputs[1].ScriptPubKey;

        payment.Sign(secret, false); // the problem arises here

        using (var node = Node.Connect(Network.Main))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Doing version handshake");
            node.VersionHandshake();
            Console.WriteLine("Sending message");
            node.SendMessage(new InvPayload(InventoryType.MSG_TX, payment.GetHash()));
            node.SendMessage(new TxPayload(payment));
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed my code as follows (in case someone needs in future):

```
   public static bool SendBTC(string secret, string toAddress, decimal amount, string fundingTransactionHash)
    {
        Network bitcoinNetwork = Network.TestNet;
        var bitcoinPrivateKey = new BitcoinSecret(secret, bitcoinNetwork);
        var address = bitcoinPrivateKey.GetAddress(ScriptPubKeyType.Legacy);

        var client = new QBitNinjaClient(bitcoinNetwork);
        var transactionId = uint256.Parse(fundingTransactionHash);
        var transactionResponse = client.GetTransaction(transactionId).Result;

        var receivedCoins = transactionResponse.ReceivedCoins;

        OutPoint outPointToSpend = null;
        foreach (var coin in receivedCoins)
        {
            if (coin.TxOut.ScriptPubKey == bitcoinPrivateKey.GetAddress(ScriptPubKeyType.Legacy).ScriptPubKey)
            {
                outPointToSpend = coin.Outpoint;
            }
        }

        var transaction = Transaction.Create(bitcoinNetwork);
        transaction.Inputs.Add(new TxIn()
        {
            PrevOut = outPointToSpend
        });

        var receiverAddress = BitcoinAddress.Create(toAddress, bitcoinNetwork);


        var txOutAmount = new Money(amount, MoneyUnit.BTC);

        // Tx fee
        var minerFee = new Money(0.0005m, MoneyUnit.BTC);

        // Change
        var txInAmount = (Money)receivedCoins[(int)outPointToSpend.N].Amount;
        var changeAmount = txInAmount - txOutAmount - minerFee;

        transaction.Outputs.Add(txOutAmount, receiverAddress.ScriptPubKey);
        transaction.Outputs.Add(changeAmount, bitcoinPrivateKey.GetAddress(ScriptPubKeyType.Legacy).ScriptPubKey);


        transaction.Inputs[0].ScriptSig = address.ScriptPubKey;

        //Sign Tx
        transaction.Sign(bitcoinPrivateKey, receivedCoins.ToArray());

        //Broadcast Tx
        BroadcastResponse broadcastResponse = client.Broadcast(transaction).Result;

        return broadcastResponse.Success;
    }
```